# How to trigger animations in horizontal layout

Tags: javascript, css-animations, horizontal-scrolling

I want to trigger CSS animations in a horizontal layout, only when the animated element gets in the viewport. I would also like to have them triggered every time they come into the viewport, not just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) can watch for elements positions in any scroll direction, can perform actions on them when they enter/leave the viewport, and can repeat those actions each time these events happen. It is very efficient and well-supported. Here is a basic example:

```
// Get an array of elements to watch
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.foo');

// Set an observer to watch their position relative to the viewport boundaries
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        // If this item is in the viewport
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            // Do some code on that item
            entry.target.classList.toggle('animated');
        }
    });
}, { rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px' });

// Tell each element to be watched
elements.forEach(el => {
    observer.observe(el);
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, I just don't understand JavaScript enough to make this work. Could you be so kind as to provide a working example, Here's may layout: https://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/8ro96stc/15/

Comment: Here is a new fiddle. I adjusted a few of your CSS properties and removed the initial class on the first section in the HTML. The observer is watching for sections as they are more than 25% visible in the viewport and adding the "slideUp" class, and removing them when they are not. https://jsfiddle.net/ks3dwh9p/

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I really appreciate it. The only thing I'm not so happy about is the way the animated elements are still visible before the animation takes place. I've fixed this by setting their initial opacity to 0. The problem with this is they will often disappear while still insight as you scroll. This new fiddle shows you what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/3q9dfr8b/19/ Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I set the threshold to 0 so the animations will not be triggered until the section is fully in/out of the viewport. I also simplified your CSS animation because you don't really need keyframes unless you plan to do something more complex later. Does this solve it? https://jsfiddle.net/6asr3u0b/

Comment: You're the best! Thank you so much. I think the threshold at 0.25 works best. I think your adjustments to the animation is what really fixed it. I've tested it in my project, reduced the translateY to just 20% and now everything performs just as it should. You've really made my day. Best wishes!

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck on the project